# jQuery Plugin Date and Time Picker creating issue in design

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, datetimepicker

I am using JQuery date time picker from this [Example](http://aspforums.net/Threads/148989/Solved-Implement-jQuery-DateTimePicker-in-ASPNet/)
It works fine and somehow it messes the design.

Heres the code i am adding :

```
<link href="Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Below code tried writing 

after body ends

after html ends

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DOB" runat="server" BackColor="#D7D7D7" BorderColor="#3399FF" BorderStyle="Groove"  Text="" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="DOB_TextChanged"   ></asp:TextBox>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('[id$=DOB]').datetimepicker({
        startDate: '+1971/05/01'//or 1986/12/08
    });
</script>
```

If you needs any part of the code do let me know, as its long so not putting it yet.

[image: Before adding JQuery]

[image: After adding JQuery]

Thanks

Comment: First, it is bad syntax to add and html elements after you have closed the `<body>` or `<html>` elements, and my first suggestion would be to move these script elements back inside of the body.  Second, we really could use more information, as "How" does it mess up the design.

Comment: @Mike I have tried adding after form closes and before too but same result . I have added screenshot

Comment: you should be able to see via chrome inspector which rules applies to the offending inputs from the calendar and make the needed adjustments.

Comment: How are your fields aligned? Table or boostrap? Other? Can you provide a simple demo?

Comment: @IrvinDominin not sure , but it is Bootstrap. How can I be sure?

Comment: @Bart any tutorial how to use chrome inspector. Sorry if I sound novice.

Comment: @mark you are sure by looking the code and the markup, can you provide it? For chrome inspector, here is the reference: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools